# What is the correct way to read sys.stdin in iPython qtconsole

Tags: python, cross-platform, ipython

I'm trying to write a library that will work as well across platforms as standard Python, iPython and within qtConsole.

Everything works except my keyboard interaction.

I want things like 'press any key' or 'press Y/N/Esc'

In Windows this is easy with msvcrt and kbhit. (though I've not tried qtconsole in windows)
In Linux this works using stdin and termios under both Python and iPython.

The trouble is it seems qtconsole uses non-blocking stdin and does not support termios.

You would think this would be a good thing, simply flush stdin then check it for a character.  The problem is this seems not to work.  It never returns a character.  It is as though ipython itself is getting in the way of stdin being fed by the terminal.

What is the correct way to read sys.stdin in qtconsole?

(BTW, there is no tag for qtconsole, this question is about qtconsole, not just iPython)

Comment: `QtConsole` is not a terminal, it's some kind of widget written using `Qt`, so it probably have a "buffer" somewhere where it puts the characters and sends to stdin only one line at a time.
If you want something simple and that works everywhere just tell the user to press `Enter`.

Comment: I guessed that, but I can't find where in it's class hierarchy that buffer exists or how to access it.

Comment: The definition of the qt console widget can be found in the directory `IPython/frontend/qt/console` of the sources. by what I see it's a plain QWidget which catches `QKeyPress` events and dispatch them to other objects. The input is handled differently during execution of commands, so it's not trivial to understand exactly how the input is handled when your command runs.

Comment: The Qt console doesn't really replicate stdin at present, it only forwards the input when Python code calls `input()` or `raw_input()`. So I don't think you can do more advanced terminal things in it.