# Why standard input redirect not work in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

**Background:**

I want to simulate `python xxx.py < file.txt` in code, the `xxx.py` will expect `user input`, here the `stdin` redirect to `file.txt`.

So I have following code to simulate the redirection:

**try.py:**

```
import sys
f = open('file.txt', 'w')
f.write('"Tom"')
f.write('\n')
f.write('"Jerry"')
f.write('\n')
f.close()

sys.stdin = open('file.txt')

for i in range(2):
    val = input()
    print('Say hello to: ' + val)

sys.stdin = sys.__stdin__ # restore stdin
```

Above works perfectly in windows cmd as follows:

```
C:\work>python try.py
Say hello to: Tom
Say hello to: Jerry
```

**Question:**

Then, I paste it to `jupyter notebook`, and click run. It still give me a `input text box` to let me enter something for `input`.

Why the `standard input redirect` no effect here when I run it in `jupyter notebook`? `Jupyter notebook` do something special to run our code? What we may pay attention later to run code in `Jupyter`? Please suggest.

**NOTE:** to make things clear, I paste the picture here, the code exactly same as above in `try.py`.

[image]

Comment: I assume Jupyter notebooks are already doing something funky with stdin

Comment: Have you tried entering nothing? What is the result?

Comment: consider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49877747/replacing-standard-input-with-a-string-in-python3-using-jupyter

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, seems it does. But if any document mention all funky things about jupyter? I don't want to jump into trap again for other code later.

Comment: @Sraw If enter nothing, it print `Say hello to:`, and then let me input the next.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it could be a workaround with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49877747/replacing-standard-input-with-a-string-in-python3-using-jupyter, but my concern is what jupyter does here, so I can avoid to jump to any trap again.

Comment: Another relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396653/what-is-the-correct-way-to-read-sys-stdin-in-ipython-qtconsole

Comment: Yeah, honestly, I don't think Jupyter Notebooks are designed with this sort of use-case in mind. They are a sort of literate programming tool for interactive data-analysis / visualization. '

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, I really agree with you for the scenario, just a little curious when see this issue. Maybe I need to just use it for small piece of code test later in my work, avoid to do such kind of things in the post.